# Null and Id in Rails on Destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, destroy

Is there a way to set a sort of `dependent:destroy` that will null an id but not destroy the record? For instance, I have a Order model that contains information about a patron's orders. I also have a Patron model that contains info about the patron. When I destroy a patron, I'd like all the ids for that patron (patron_id) in Order to be null now, so as to avoid weird mixups with new patrons, should that id be reused. However, I still want to keep the Order record for analysis of what was ordered the most, etc. Is there a relationship that defines this?

Example:

**Order**

- order_id
- patron_id
- order_info

**Patron**

- patron_id
- patron_name

A patron `has_many: orders`. An order `belongs_to: patron`
Lets say I have patrons [{1,'Bob'},{2,'Sally'}]
And orders [{1,2,'Cake'},{2,2,'Screwdriver'},{3,1,'Ham'}]
Then I destroy sally, making patrons [{1,'Bob'}].
I'd want orders to be [{1,null,'Cake'},{2,null,'Screwdriver'},{3,1,'Ham'}]

How would I do this?

Comment: it looks like you need `dependent: :nullify` (see chanpter [4.2.2.4 :dependent](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)). But I am not sure. Please provide an example which describes expected behavior.

Comment: @gotva looking into that now. I've added an example above.

Comment: @gotva That looks like precisely what I need. Formulate into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You could also use `paranoia` gem and configure your patrons as paranoid so deleting them would populate the field deleted_at and remove them from any future queries on patrons. https://github.com/radar/paranoia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use option `nullify`

```
has_many :orders, dependent: :nullify
```

see more details in chapter [4.2.2.4 :dependent](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)